# Knockout.js data-bind: click, runs on page load

Tags: asp.net-mvc, typescript, knockout.js

I have a table with a `foreach` binding. I wan't to create a button that will trigger a function when clicked. Instead the function runs automatically on page load.

I've tried to use a button or empty `<td>` element with the `click` binding. The results are the same.

CSHTML

```
<td>

  <button type="button" 
          class="btn btn-primary" 
          data-bind="click: QuickReplyToSpecificRequestByManager(@item.Id)"
  >Accept</button>

</td>
```

TS

```
public QuickReplyToSpecificRequestByManager(obs) {

    var data = {
        idToPass: obs,
        Description: "Approved",
        Status: 3
    };
    if (data.idToPass == undefined) {
        console.log("Id missing");
    } else {

        console.log(obs);
        $.post("/Request/SubmitReplyRequestDetails", data)
            .done(function () {
                console.log("Success");
                window.location.reload();
            });
    }
};
```

I would excpect to run function only when I click the button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you `applyBindings`, knockout evaluates all its binding strings.

In the case of `click: QuickReplyToSpecificRequestByManager(@item.Id)`, it will initialize the `click` binding (left of the `:`), by evaluating the part right of the `:`.

Since `QuickRepl...` is a function, and it's followed by `( ... )`, it's being called.

To fix it, you can `bind` the injected value without calling:

```
click: QuickReplyToSpecificRequestByManager.bind($data, @item.Id)
```